# Jquery for changed field but also initial load

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have Rails app with the following jquery (coffeescript) code:

```
woassets = $('#workorder_woasset_id').html()
$('#workorder_location_id').change ->
  group2 = $('#workorder_location_id :selected').text()
  options2 = $(woassets).filter("optgroup[label='#{group2}']").html()
  if options2
    $('#workorder_woasset_id').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>' + options2)
    $('#workorder_woasset_id').parent().show()
  else
    $('#workorder_woasset_id').empty()
```

It works great when you select a Location, the Woasset list is filtered to only associated records.

But, if the Location is pre-selected when you first see the page, no change has happened - so, the Woasset isn't filtered.

Is there a way to trigger the filter when the page first loads?

Thanks for you help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#workorder_location_id').trigger('change');
```

should do it.